# Laravel template showing two blade templates from route

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have a full html template, that I am trying to use with laravel. 
The template has a big image slider (that should only be in homepage) and a couple of other codes like contact form, accordion, twitter widget... my goal is to place those parts in separate blade templates and call them when needed. For this, I have this folder scheme.

```
..
/views
  /emails
  /home
    - slider.blade.php
    - contact-form.blade.php
    - twitterwidget.blade.php
  /layouts
    - master.blade.php
```

So, for example `master.blade.php` looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='header'>
  //header 
  @yield('slider')
 </div>

 <div class='content'>
  //content
   @yield('contact-form')
 </div>

 <div class='footer'>
  //footer
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now that is a basic examples which `yields` a slider inside the headers tags, and this is the `slider.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('details')
<div class='slider'> I am a slider </div>
@stop
```

but when I create a route, I am forced to create one point to one template. as:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return   View::make('home/slider');
});
```

This only renders the layout by pulling the slider. But I want to contact form to be rendered also.

Comment: You should edit your question and but `slider.blade.php` source

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Ok, but it has nothing to do with the template. Read the last line of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `master.blade.php` file instead of

```
@yield('contact-form')
```

you should use:

```
@include('home.contact-form')
```

or you can edit your `slider.blade.php` file and add at the end:

```
@section('contact-form')
    @include('home.contact-form')
@stop
```

Comment: I can't do the first one, because the master template is sharable according many pages, that don't need to show the contact-form. But I tried your section option, and it did not work. It did not include the contact form.

Comment: @CONtext Please include also `contact-form.blade.php` content to your question

Comment: It is exactly the same as slider.blade.php it just says "I am a contact form" (this is for testing purpose)

Comment: BTW: Do you have an suggestions about my stupid routing i.e `return   View::make('home/slider');` I could change `slider.blade.php` to `index.blade.php` but, it would be wrong since it only contains a slide and includes the contact form.

Comment: I would create files with just content (without yielding or extending) and then in for example index.blade.php yield 2 blockes using include as I showed earlier for slider